# Transition between 2 page in viewpager not work smoothly

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I work on viewpager with 3 fragment, I also have 3 action bar tab.
I can change page by click tab or swipe below tab.

The animation work very smooth if :

1. I change page by click action bar tab
2. If my finger move slowly to left or right to change page
3. If my finger move slowly then get off my finger from screen (it back to previous screen)

But the problem is when I swipe my finger fast, the transition between previous and next page have some freeze moment, although it just below 1 second.

I only using normal viewpager and custom scroller to slow animation speed. Here is my code

mainactivity:

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);


try {
      Field mScroller;
      mScroller = ViewPager.class.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
      mScroller.setAccessible(true);
      myScroller scroller = new myScroller(viewPager.getContext(), new DecelerateInterpolator()); 
      mScroller.set(viewPager, scroller);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    }
```

i need help to make transition between page work smoothly, and i prefer not to use additional lib from outside (example : jazzy view pager) if possible.
thanks in advance

**EDIT: add scroller class**

```
public class myScroller extends Scroller {

private int mDuration = 400;

public myScroller(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public myScroller(Context context, Interpolator interpolator) {
    super(context, interpolator);
}

public myScroller(Context context, Interpolator interpolator, boolean flywheel) {
    super(context, interpolator, flywheel);
}


@Override
public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
    // Ignore received duration, use fixed one instead
    super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, mDuration);
}

@Override
public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy) {
    // Ignore received duration, use fixed one instead
    super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, mDuration);
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe increase the page offset limit by  ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit() can help. It's increase the number of pages created so maybe it's reduce the lag when swipe.

Comment: Hi Minhtdh, yes i already put it in my code

Comment: You extern the scroller then set again in viewPager? Have you try the behaviour when don't set scroller? Maybe it's your Scroller, can you post your Scroller code?

Comment: Yes, i need that to slow page transition, i just edit my post to add my scroller code. yes i try it without my scroller,but it have same behavior

Comment: why you have DecelerateInterpolator in your scroller ?

Comment: I want the page move slower before end transition, should i remove it? i change to another interpolator?

Comment: try with LinearInterpolator once..

Comment: changed to LinearInterpolator, its still have lag after my finger get off from screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i found the problem,

here is condition my old code:
i have 2 page with list view. when i swipe it, i load all again my list view on the second page.

when i remove my code to load all list view, transition between page work smooth. it seems to load the list view first then it load animation page change.

Answer (score 0):

Below are some good working example of the same implementation that you are looking for.

1. https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/ActionBar
2. https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ActionBar-Tabs-with-Fragments
3. http://androidtechnicalblog.blogspot.in/2014/02/using-viewpager-to-swipe-between.html

Comment: Hi Murtuza , thanks for the answer. but my problem is animation transition between page if swipe it.